# Rails (Object doesn't support #inspect) / NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model "Section". Whenever I try to iterate over Section object, like, "Section.all" or "Section.create", I get error as "(Object doesn't support #inspect)" in Rails console and "NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)" in the terminal.

***Ruby: ruby 2.6.1p33***

***Rails: 5.2.3***

**Section migration**

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :students_count, :default => 0
      t.references :class, index: true
      t.references :class_teacher, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :sections, :standards, column: :class_id
    add_foreign_key :sections, :users, column: :class_teacher_id
  end
end
```

**Section model**

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :class, :class_name => "Standard", :foreign_key => "standard_id"
  belongs_to :class_teacher, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "class_teacher_id"
end
```

**Controller code**

```
def index
  @sections = Section.where(:class_id => params[:class_id])

  render json: @sections
end
```

**Terminal output**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

**Rails console Input**

```
Section.all
```

**Rails console output**

```
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Strangely, when Section table is empty, console output is

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: At a guess, this is probably the problem: `belongs_to :class, :class_name => "Standard", :foreign_key => "standard_id"`. This will try to define a method `Section#class`, which conflicts with `Object#class`. In general, it's a bad idea to ever call something `class` in the code. If you really can't think of an alternative name (e.g. `class_group`?), call it `klass` (with a `k`).

Comment: By the way, I once worked on a school application for a while.. We ran into this sort of problem quite often. Turns out software and the education system often conflict over "key words"... For example, names like `parent` and `child` can also cause issues if you're not careful!

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for your detailed explanation. This was the problem. I used Standard instead of Class and it worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @TomLord, I also have a Parent model. Can it create a similar issue?

Comment: Not for this specific thing... But you may need to be careful if, for example, you generate XML where "parent" has a special meaning.

Comment: Will keep this in mind @TomLord. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the @Tom Lord's comment, you have to correct the associations:

```rb
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :class, class_name: "Standard"                    
  belongs_to :class_teacher, class_name: "User"
end
```

Since your migration creates a `class_id` and `class_teacher_id` for references, the right FK names are those.

You need to set FK on the has_many models:

```rb
class Standard < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections, foreign_key: :class_id
end
```

UPDATE: 
FK are always created on the *belongs_to* tables. As the association you set is named `class`, Rails expect a column named `class_id` to be present on the table, which it has, that's why you don't need to set FK in the `belongs_to` model.

In the other hand, Rails can't infer the FK in the `has_many` model because it is expecting a column named `standard_id` on the table `sections`, but it is named `class_id`, so you need set the correct column name by hand.

Hope it helps.

Comment: CAmador you are absolutely right. But I have already defined the associations properly. This was an issue with "class" class_name as mentioned by Tom. Thanks :)